# What does the star means in wpf intellisnse dropdown list?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml

Working with WPF, the intellisense dropdown list entries shows icons on left which means the [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019). But the article doesn't say what the additional star means that shows additionally with some items (shown below)?

Or is it

> Protected. Accessible from the containing class or type, or those
>   derived from the containing class or type.

Does it mean its the protected property of the class (in this case ComboBox) that I am working with in XAML?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is not the symbol for protected access. It is a feature of IntelliCode which brings the most relevant choices to the top and prefixes them with a star:

> IntelliCode provides AI-assisted IntelliSense in both Visual Studio
>   and Visual Studio Code. IntelliCode suggestions appear at the top of
>   the completion list with a star icon next to them

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/intellicode/overview

Comment: I like this feature, but I read the article you posted, as well as its associated links, and it looks like this is only AI-based.  Are you aware of an Attribute we can apply that would force Intellisense to add specific properties to its list?